# Only use explicit filters, disable filtering with project properties

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to prevent Maven resource interpolation from resolving environment variables.

Environment variables are available as ["implicit project properties"](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html). The resources plugin only offers an option to ["don't use the filters specified in the build/filters section"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html#useBuildFilters), which is the opposite of I want.

Is there a way to achive this without fiddling directly with `org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesExecution`?

If not  I'd appreciate some hints on how to configure `MavenResourcesExecution` class to use only a given filter list and not project properties.

---

Looks like `BaseFilter` will always inject project properties if a `MavenProject` is available [#97](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared/blob/trunk/maven-filtering/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/BaseFilter.java#L97) [#133](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared/blob/trunk/maven-filtering/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/BaseFilter.java#L133).
If that's true it seems the most promising way is to setup a `MavenResourcesExecution` instance without a `MavenProject`. (GMaven plugin to the rescue?)

Comment: Are we talking about a Maven build or are you creating something programmatically ? If you don't set filtering on it won't happen ? Can you give a full example what you are trying to do?

Comment: @khmarbaise please check the demo here: https://github.com/jakub-bochenski/maven-filtering-explicit/tree/master

Comment: @khmarbaise can you offer any help then?